# Get the sum of a column without affecting the grouping of three columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

my query looks like this;

```
SELECT count(visitor_city) as cnt, page_id, page_type, visitor_city, visitor_state
FROM visitors
GROUP BY page_id, page_type, visitor_city
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

The above works fine, but I also want to get the SUM of all 'count' per the grouping.

I need to add the SUM of 'count'.

The reason being, the initial query gets the UNIQUE visitors to the page, but I also want to get the overall visits to the page. 'count' column holds the multiple views from each ip.

EDIT:

I did not realize that just adding SUM(count) as .. will not affect the grouping.

```
SELECT count(page_id) as cnt, page_id, page_type, visitor_city, visitor_state, SUM(count) as pv 
FROM visitors GROUP BY page_id, page_type, visitor_city 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

did the job.

Comment: `The above works fine` ... no it doesn't, this query will not run at all.

Comment: It is working fine currently displaying the results now.

Comment: Your query has another problem: You are selecting `visitor_state`, but this column does not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  sum(OriginalCount.cnt), OriginalCount.page_id, OriginalCount.page_type, OriginalCount.visitor_city, OriginalCount.visitor_state
from 
(SELECT count(visitor_city) as cnt, page_id, page_type, visitor_city, visitor_state
    FROM visitors
    GROUP BY page_id, page_type, visitor_city, visitor_state
    ) as OriginalCount
group by OriginalCount.page_id, OriginalCount.page_type, OriginalCount.visitor_city, OriginalCount.visitor_state
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: What I have works now Shep, my question is how do I get the SUM of the column called 'count' without affecting the group